# Dell Laptops Dedicated video memory size 0mb?

Tags: dell-latitude

I have a Dell Lattitude e6430 which has no graphics card. In Bios the Video Memory is 64mb but when I go to the adapter setting of display it shows 0mb. How to increase that value?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> which has no graphics card

It has no *dedicated* graphics card, but has an *integrated* one. Integrated into CPU, specifically.

> In Bios the Video Memory is 64mb

I don't remember any such setting from E6430 BIOS, but it's probably minimum amount of RAM reserved for the integrated GPU.

> it shows 0mb

This integrated GPU has no dedicated memory, it shares some with the rest of the system, so 0 MB of dedicated memory is correct. On the screenshot 1792 MB is shared (borrowed from RAM for GPU use). Out of this 1792 MB, 64 MB is the initial allocation you've set in BIOS.

> How to increase that value?

You can't, it's how integrated GPUs are built. It doesn't matter though, there's no practical difference.